# Two questions about $p$-groups of class $2$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a $p$-group of class $2$. Then $G'\subseteq Z(G)$.

Consider following four groups:
$$G', Z(G), G/G', G/Z(G).$$
There is some relations between invariantes of these groups.

**(1)**  Exponent$(G')=$Exponent$(G/Z(G)$.

**(2)** Rank$(Z(G))\geq$Rank$(G')$ and Rank$(G/Z(G))\leq$ Rank$(G/G')$.

> **Q.1.** In the second relation, is it true that at least one equality holds?

Considering  (1), it is natural to ask about relation between exponents of  remaining two groups:

> **Q.2** Is there any relation(equality/inequality) between Exponent$(Z(G))$ and Exponent$(G/G')$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1**

Suppose $p$ is odd.

Let $T$ be the non-abelian $p$-group of exponent $p$ and order $p^3$. Let $V$ be an elementary abelian $p$-group of rank $n\geqslant 2$. Let $G=T\times V$.

Then $Z(G)=Z(T)\times V$ and $G'=T'=Z(T)$.

Hence $G/G'\simeq \mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_p\times V$ and $G/Z(G)\simeq\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_p$.

The inequalities in (2) are both strict.

Comment: I think $G/G'$ should be $(T/T')\times V$ and it can not be $\mathbb{Z}_p\times V$.

Comment: Also, perhaps you are considering $T$ of order $p^3$ only.

Comment: Thanks, @Beginner, I will correct these errors.

Answer (score 1):

To save typing, I will write $E(G)$ for the exponent of $G$.

For Question 2, $E(G/Z(G)) = E(G')$ and $G' \le Z(G)$ imply $E(G') \le E(G/G')$ and $E(G/Z(G)) \le E(Z(G))$.  Hence
$$E(Z(G)) \le E(G) \le E(G')E(G/G') \le E(G/G')^2$$ and
$$E(G/G') \le E(G) \le E(G/Z(G))E(Z(G)) \le E(Z(G))^2.$$
The examples $$\langle a,b,c \mid a^{p^k} = b^{p^k}=c^{p^{2k}}=1, [a,b]=c^{p^k}, [a,c]=[b,c]=1 \rangle$$ and
$$\langle a,b,c \mid a^{p^{2k}} = b^{p^{2k}}=c^{p^{k}}=1, [a,b]=c, [a,c]=[b,c]=1 \rangle$$
show that both of these bounds are best possible.